# eaframework outputstream doesn't work on 11.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstream, external-accessory

```
- (void)_writeData {
    while (([[_session outputStream] hasSpaceAvailable]) && ([_writeData length] > 0))
    {
        NSInteger bytesWritten = [[_session outputStream] write:[_writeData bytes] maxLength:[_writeData length]];
        if (bytesWritten == -1) {
            NSLog(@"write error");
            break;
        } else if (bytesWritten > 0) {
            [_writeData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, bytesWritten) withBytes:NULL length:0];
            NSLog(@"bytesWritten %ld", (long)bytesWritten);
        }
    }
}
```

I code exactly same as Apple's official demo as above, the communication with external accessory via lightning port works fine except on "iOS 11.2.1".

I debugged and found that it really did the action of sending out data by `Outputstream`, but failed anyhow, detect no data out.

anybody know how to find out what's going on inside the stream? 
is this a bug of Apple?

Comment: any update on above issue ,i am facing same issue while writing data to external device. I have tested with iOS 10.3.3 and iOS 11.2 and above code is not working.

Comment: @sumitkumar I checked 11.2.2 the latest version till now, no progress out there. How about you?

Comment: nah not yet, but can u help me with iOS 10.3.3 because mine is not working

Comment: @sumitkumar about your 10.3.3 I dont know the exactly reason cause I have nothing special code for system version related, though one thing it might be helpful is that please check with your hardware engineer about the command he sent to setup communication with iOS system, cause my side faced this kind of problem before and our hardware engineer changed command according the apple mfi documents and fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved:

1.**Hardware side** send `StatusExternalAccessoryProtocolSession` command as instructed in `Accessory Interface Specification R27.pdf`

Weird things is that in the version lower than 11.2, the session is able to setup success without this command.